# How to make Chrome remember page size?

Tags: google-chrome

One of the things i like about Firefox is that it remembers the font size you chose for any webpage visited while it keeps your default size for all the others.

Can Google Chrome be configured in this way too?

Comment: That's `by-design`, or am I missing something? I use Chrome on OS X, and every site I've zoomed in before stays like this.

Comment: @slhck - yeah same here

Comment: @slhck It's by site, and the OP is asking for by page.

Comment: Well, i'm on Windows7 and Chrome isn't doing it on any page (after closing browser). In fact, most browsers keep the zoomed in size for every page you visit until you un-zoom it.